# Add Missing Vendor specifics in Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I can't for the life of me get add missing vendor specifics to work in VS.

If i click the shortcut nothing happens - the cursor just moves to the top of the file?

[image: Add shortcut]

I used to get squigly lines under items that needed extra vendor specifics but this seems to have disappeared in 2015 too?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in my case too, probably the extension installation is broken